# sajda sahw before or after tasleem in this case?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sharia, sajda

I was praying isha and then I accidentally did something extra, so I knew I have to do sajda sahw and continued praying but then towards the end I kind of delayed the salams because I was thinking about whether to do the extra prostrations immediately or not. Then I just did tasleem and sajda sahw afterwards. Is my prayer valid?

Comment: I don't understand why you think prayer would be invalid. The most I see is "delayed the salams because I was thinking about whether to do the extra prostrations," but since when does thinking break the prayer

Comment: I overthink things easily so that’s why I wanted to ask

Comment: Be aware that different maddhabs have different views some only do sujud as-Sahw before Salam, others only after it and the thirds depending on the case before or after. Without knowing which maddhabs you follow it might be unclear what is the correct way here.

Comment: I don’t only follow one because sometimes there seems to more evidence for one opinion, sometimes for the other. Is this okay? Or do I have to follow just one of them?